# animation won't run first time

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

i have a weird bug.  When my app loads and i tap a button to do a animation it doesn't commit to the animation but when i try the second time it works perfectly.  Heres my code:

```
-(void)Revert
{

    firstTable.hidden = FALSE;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = NO;
    [self returnanimation];
}

-(void)returnanimation
{
    CGRect labelframe = childnamelabel.frame;
    labelframe.origin.x = 493.5; // new x coordinate
    labelframe.origin.y = 359; // new y coordinate
    CGRect textframe = passwordfield.frame;
    textframe.origin.x = 454; // new x coordinate
    textframe.origin.y = 388; // new y coordinate
    CGRect submitframe = submit.frame;
    submitframe.origin.x = 640; // new x coordinate
    submitframe.origin.y = 387; // new y coordinate

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
    childnamelabel.frame = labelframe;
    passwordfield.frame = textframe;
    submit.frame = submitframe;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)animation
{


    CGRect labelframe = childnamelabel.frame;
    labelframe.origin.x = 335.5; // new x coordinate
    labelframe.origin.y = 359; // new y coordinate
    CGRect textframe = passwordfield.frame;
    textframe.origin.x = 294; // new x coordinate
    textframe.origin.y = 388; // new y coordinate
    CGRect submitframe = submit.frame;
    submitframe.origin.x = 480; // new x coordinate
    submitframe.origin.y = 387; // new y coordinate
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];

    childnamelabel.frame = labelframe;
    passwordfield.frame = textframe;
    submit.frame = submitframe;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)PressedTeacherButton: (UIBarButtonItem*) Teacherbutton
{
    [self setNameLabel: @"Mrs Hayward" Child:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    firstTable.hidden = TRUE;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(Revert)];
    [self animation];

    //Pass on admins name and also bool whether they are a child.
}
```

Tried looking for solutions but couldn't find anything.  Thanks for the help :D

*UPDATE

Narrowed it down to the `[self setNameLabel: @"Mrs Hayward" Child:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];` it seems the animation doesn't like changing the labels before animating nor after.  I've tried the completion feature, it animates then immediately resets to old position after changing the label.

REQUEST BY BOT TO PUT UP setnamelabel method:

```
- (void) setNameLabel:(NSString *)sender Child:(NSNumber *)Child
{
    self.childnamelabel.text = sender;
    IsAChild = Child;
}
```

Still unanswered :(

Comment: post your `sentNameLabel:Child:` method code.

Comment: What iOS version are you using?

Comment: i'm using iOS version 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Although your code looks fine, I had a similar issue awhile back. I switched to using a block and it worked.

try using

```
-(void)animation
{
    CGRect labelframe = childnamelabel.frame;
    labelframe.origin.x = 335.5; // new x coordinate
    labelframe.origin.y = 359; // new y coordinate
    CGRect textframe = passwordfield.frame;
    textframe.origin.x = 294; // new x coordinate
    textframe.origin.y = 388; // new y coordinate
    CGRect submitframe = submit.frame;
    submitframe.origin.x = 480; // new x coordinate
    submitframe.origin.y = 387; // new y coordinate

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        childnamelabel.frame = labelframe;
        passwordfield.frame = textframe;
        submit.frame = submitframe;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately it didn't make any different, tried doing the animation off the start to preload it and still nothing !  Makes no sense :(

Comment: Okay.  i commented out   [self setNameLabel: @"Mrs Hayward" Child:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; and it worked this time.  Odd error, but i'm going to try working around it :)

Comment: For convenience of other viewers.  The method i commented out in the previous comment was changing a label that was going to be animated, it seems it doesn't like you changing the values just before you animate.  A weird error :P, have to do the completion thing after the animation

Comment: ARGH, even if i put completion section on the animation, it changes then instantly returns to the previous position.  This annoys me so much :'(

Comment: @user1816481 post the code for that method. Something in that method is screwing it up.

Comment: No its not the method.  All its doing is changing the label text.  Thats what the Mrs Hayward argument is for.  So assume its the label text.  This is the code inside method:    childnamelabel.text = sender;

Comment: @user1816481 then why are you passing a child?

Comment: Its completely out of the question because i even pulled the childnamelabel.text = sender out of the method and into the animation method itself, i commented out the setnamelabel method but when i put in the childnamelabel.text it doesn't like it.  Else it runs as it should.  I don't know if this is a bug, or i'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: @user1816481 again we ask that you post the code. you shouldn't set text to a sender so this could be an issue.

Comment: Its not, sorry it wasn't the sender when i changed it.  It was             childnamelabel.text = @"Mrs Hayward"; when i put it into the main method and the same thing occurs.  BUT when i comment this out it works fine.  So its this statement.  BUT ! if your still going to keep on about the method then i'll update it -,-